# Defunctorizer for OCaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

In the past, Julien Signoles programmed `ocamldefun`, a program that took OCaml source code with functors and obtained an equivalent program without functors. This is useful for optimization, analysis and other purposes.

It seems that `ocamldefun` is no longer maintained. Does there exist some equivalent tool?

Comment: I'm not sure how much work it would be to re-implement something like that -- maybe not *that* much. I'm wondering what the motivation is, though, because running Coq programs on top of F# isn't a terribly exciting perspective.

Comment: I have very good reasons to want to run Coq programs in F# indeed. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Markus Mottl showed a camlp4 trick to do compile time functor instantiation (with some limitation). Take a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/ocaml-prog-pats/overview)